# Making a user control pulse

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, code-behind

What I'm trying to do is make my control "pulse" (as in enlarge a bit, then shrink a bit, then back to its normal size).  The following code does exactly what I want, but it just seems like there should be a simpler way.  It has to be done in code behind because this is an abstract class that most of our controls derive from.  I don't have much experience with animation controls and story boards.

So specifically my question is, is there a simpler way to get the desired results than the following method (while still being done in the code-behind)?

```
    public void Pulse()
    {
        var storyboard = new Storyboard
        {
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
            RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2)
        };

        double timeIncrement = .15;
        double changePercent = 20;

        var firstTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIncrement);
        var secondTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIncrement * 3);
        var thirdTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIncrement * 4);

        var scale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);

        RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
        RenderTransform = scale;

        //enlarge
        {
            DoubleAnimation growX = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = firstTime,
                To = 1 + changePercent
            };
            storyboard.Children.Add(growX);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growX, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));

            DoubleAnimation growY = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = firstTime,
                To = 1 + changePercent
            };
            storyboard.Children.Add(growY);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growY, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));
        }

        //shrink
        {
            DoubleAnimation shrinkX = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = secondTime,
                To = 1 - changePercent
            };
            storyboard.Children.Add(shrinkX);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shrinkX, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));

            DoubleAnimation shrinkY = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = secondTime,
                To = 1 - changePercent
            };
            storyboard.Children.Add(shrinkY);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(shrinkY, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));
        }

        //back to normal
        {
            DoubleAnimation normX = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = thirdTime,
                To = 1
            };
            storyboard.Children.Add(normX);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(normX, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));

            DoubleAnimation normY = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = thirdTime,
                To = 1
            };
            storyboard.Children.Add(normY);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(normY, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));
        }

        BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, false);
    }
```

Comment: That looks fairly simple to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fine way of doing it, WPF does not provide methods or events to automatically pulse. Yours is simple and as you've created it, you know how to modify it as you wish.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I assumed there had to be animation somewhere that I was missing that would make this simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps simplify things *a little* by moving your grow/shrink logic into its own method. This reduces duplication and provides a potentially more reusable code kibble.

```
public void Pulse()
{
    var storyboard = new Storyboard
    {
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
        RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2)
    };

    double timeIncrement = .15;

    double growPercent = 20;
    double shrinkPercent = -20;

    var firstTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIncrement);
    var secondTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIncrement * 3);
    var thirdTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeIncrement * 4);

    var scale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);

    RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
    RenderTransform = scale;

    storyboard = AddSizeChange(firstTime, growPercent, storyboard);
    storyboard = AddSizeChange(secondTime, shrinkPercent, storyboard);
    storyboard = AddSizeChange(thirdTime, growPercent, storyboard);

    BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, false);
}

public Storyboard AddSizeChange(TimeSpan animTime, double changePercent, Storyboard storyboard)
{
    DoubleAnimation growX = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        Duration = animTime,
        To = 1 + changePercent
    };
    storyboard.Children.Add(growX);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growX, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));

    DoubleAnimation growY = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        Duration = animTime,
        To = 1 + changePercent
    };
    storyboard.Children.Add(growY);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growY, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));

    return storyboard;
}
```